# Lock down InfoPath Templates

Tags: sharepoint, ms-office, infopath

Does anyone know how to prevent users from editing an InfoPath form in Design mode? Users are storing InfoPath forms in SharePoint and it seems that anyone can edit the form in design mode and we need to be able to lock that down.

Answer (score 2):

The only way to stop that from happening is to publish the form template to a place they don't have access to.  I usually publish them to the "Forms Template Library" at the top level site; and lock down access that way.

edit: To clarify, users cannot open a previously saved form and edit the template that way.  They must be able to get their hands on the physical "Form Template" and that's what you have to lock down.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Group Policy item that you can disable the design button.

Have a look at this blog for infopath 2003
[Pashman's InfoPath Goldmine](http://blogs.msdn.com/timpash/archive/2006/02/08/Prevent-Design-Mode-For-Users.aspx)

For Infopath 2003

```
User Configuration
   Administrative Templates
      Microsoft Office InfoPath 2003
         Miscellaneous
             Disable InfoPath Designer Mode
```

For Infopath 2007
[Microsoft Security TechCenter](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148230.aspx)
Search for: Information Rights Management

```
User Configuration
    Administrative Templates
        Classic Administrative Templates (ADM)
            Microsoft Office InfoPath 2007
                Restricted Features
```